# Hide x values in seaborn barplot when leggend is added

Tags: python, bar-chart, seaborn

I'm using this code to plot seaborn barchars:

```
quality = {"quality":['ONE','TWO','THREE'],'Y':[80,100,120]}

ax = sns.barplot(x='quality',y='Y',
                 hue='quality',
                 palette = 'Blues_r',
                 data=quality)
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='16',fontweight='bold') # for legend text
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='16',fontweight='bold') 
ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontweight='bold',fontsize='18')
plt.show()
```

Which have the following result:

[image]

I want to improve readability of the default plot, hence I added the legend but now names are duplicated in the legend and X axis now I need to hide the values "one" "two" "three" there

[image]

Those values

Comment: add `ax.set_xticklabels('')` before `plt.show()` should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try
 `ax.set_xlabel('')` and `ax.set_xticks([])` before plt.show()

so

```
quality = {"quality":['ONE','TWO','THREE'],'Y':[80,100,120]}

ax = sns.barplot(x='quality',y='Y',
                 hue='quality',
                 palette = 'Blues_r',
                 data=quality)
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_texts(), fontsize='16',fontweight='bold') # for legend text
plt.setp(ax.get_legend().get_title(), fontsize='16',fontweight='bold') 
ax.set_ylabel('Y',fontweight='bold',fontsize='18')
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_xticks([])
plt.show()
```